# How to tell JAXB marschaller to create CDATA element?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

The problem sounds very easy, but I did not manage to get it working properly. I want to create XML, but one of the fields should be in CDATA format, as we are doing fulltext searching within so generated XMLs.

How can I tell JAXB to marschal the object while one of the field should be in CDATA block? What I tried is, I annotate the field with:

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CDATAAdapter.class)
    protected String valueCDATA;
```

And the adapter:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CDATAAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return "<![CDATA[" + v + "]]>";
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Thing is, it will escape it anyways. However if I use:

```
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.characterEscapeHandler",
                   (CharacterEscapeHandler) (ch, start, length, isAttVal, writer1) -> writer1.write(ch, start, length));
```

But this will not escape any other field. So what is the solution for this?